# Simple mysql query with ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, xcode, asiformdatarequest

I'm trying to use ASIFormDataRequest for iphone to get some values from my mysql database.

From the iphone I do this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: ServerApiURLGet]; 
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL: url]; 
[request setDelegate:self]; 
[request setPostValue:@"james" forKey:@"name"];
```

The request is send to a php files, which does this:

```
$con = mysql_connect("host","user","password");
mysql_select_db("table", $con);

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']); 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT score FROM `active_users` WHERE `nickname` ='$name';"); 

$result = mysql_fetch_array($query); 

sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
```

And the response function:

```
function sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $content_type = 'text/html')
{
$status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . getStatusCodeMessage($status);
header($status_header);
header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
echo $body;
}
```

Back to the iphone, I try to read the information from the callback like this:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{        
NSDictionary *responseDict = [[request responseString] JSONValue];

NSLog(@"responseString: %@", [request responseString]);
NSLog(@"responseHeaders: %@", [request responseHeaders]);
NSLog(@"responseDict: %@", responseDict );
}
```

But it doesn't work. I get the error:

```
2012-03-12 08:33:57.657 Test[1991:707] -JSONValue failed. Error is: Unexpected end of input
2012-03-12 08:33:57.659 Test[1991:707] responseString: 

2012-03-12 08:33:57.660 Test[1991:707] responseHeaders: {
Connection = close;
"Content-Type" = "text/html";
Date = "Mon, 12 Mar 2012 07:33:58 GMT";
Server = "Apache/2.2.6 mod_auth_kerb/5.3 PHP/5.2.17 mod_fcgid/2.3.6";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.2.17";
}
  2012-03-12 08:33:57.661 Test[1991:707] responseDict: (null)
```

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks

Edit:

Same result if I pass in a simple array:

```
    $newArray = array(
    "score1" => '1000', 
);

 sendResponse(200, json_encode($newArray));
```

**Solved:**

When I changed _GET to _POST, it works. Thanks

Comment: log the [request responseString], the response from server is not json valid. Add the log here

Comment: I updated the code with the log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just sending your result to the iPhone without JSON encoding it, so the JSONValue on the iPhone side fails to understand the result.

Try something like;

```
sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
```

to encode your result before sending it.

Comment: @user1251004 Then you'll need to add a log what actually shows up on the iPhone side to your question to help. For example, if the query does not give any result, you'll currently probably just encode "false".

Comment: I edited in the log. Seems I dont get any responseString. I also tried to pass in a simple array instead of the query from DB:  $newArray = array(
  "score1" => '1000', 
 );   But get the same result